# Ruby extract part of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, extract, delimiter

I have the following string ...

```
CN=KendallLDAPTEST Weihe,OU=CORPUSERS,OU=CORP,DC=int,DC=appriss,DC=com
```

and I need to extract `KendallLDAPTEST Weihe`

in other words I need to extract all string data between the first `=` and the first `,`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tested, works

Using regex:

```
str = "CN=KendallLDAPTESTWeihe,OU=CORPUSERS,OU=CORP,DC=int,DC=appriss,DC=com"

str[/\=(.*?),/,1]
```

For anyone re-using this, replace both instances of `here` with the characters you want to find the text in between:

```
[/\here(.*?)here/,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply break the string apart using `split` on `,` to first produce an array of `key=value` pairs, and then split those pairs on `=`.

```
str = 'CN=KendallLDAPTEST Weihe,OU=CORPUSERS,OU=CORP,DC=int,DC=appriss,DC=com'

pairs = str.split(',').map { |pair| pair.split('=') }
# => [["CN", "KendallLDAPTEST Weihe"], ["OU", "CORPUSERS"], ["OU", "CORP"], ["DC", "int"], ["DC", "appriss"], ["DC", "com"]]

pairs.first[1]
# => "KendallLDAPTEST Weihe"
```

This is somewhat naive in that it will not work if any of your data contains escaped `=` or `,` characters.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

```
str = "CN=KendallLDAPTEST Weihe,OU=CORPUSERS,OU=CORP,DC=int,DC=appriss,DC=com"
str[/=([^,]+)/, 1] # => "KendallLDAPTEST Weihe"
```

By default the regular expression will find the first match then stop. This simply finds the first `=`, then captures all characters that are not `,` until the first `','` and returns it.

Answer (score 0):

If the text you are trying to capture is always appearing on the same index you can use this:

```
the_text[3...22]
```

Comment: I need to do this for numerous different strings of different lengths

Comment: I see, then I believe @nextstep provided the best option. Sorry it was not as useful as I though it would be.